# Redirecting and passing form data after submission

Tags: javascript, python, django

On my Django page I have advanced search button in main toolbar (bootstrap navbar). Clicking on this button display modal window with advanced searching options.

Actually, I have no idea how to redirect to search results view after filling the form and clicking "Search".

I've tried to use JavaScript's window.location.replace but it results in switching to AnonymousUser and I don't know how to pass form data to my SearchResultView.

In general at the moment I only have a very simple skeleton:

```
class SearchView(TemplateView):
    """View for displaying search results."""

    template_name = 'app/search.html'
```

I am redirecting after submitting form using js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function search_click(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.replace("http://localhost:8000/app/search");
    }
</script>
```

But it causes that admin user is logged out and I am logged as anonymoususer.
How to pass data from form to validation and how to use it in my SearchView so I could make a query and display data ?

I also need some form for validating input data.

Any help, suggestions?

Comment: put some code from your view in question please

Comment: You mean after you click the button, you had logged out from django?

Comment: Yes, it logged out admin user and set user to anonymous.

Comment: Ok, in my form I set <form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="post">. Will it cause that form data will be passed to my view?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think i solved my problem :)

In HTML before my form I put:

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="post">
```

And in my views.py:

```
class SearchView(TemplateView):
    """View for displaying search results."""

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "app/search.html")
```

I am not sure only if I should inherit from FormView or find other way to get form data in my view.